# Expect/TCL: pass commands to specific proc/spawn IDs

Tags: tcl, expect, spawn

I am trying to write an expect script that will do the following..

open up 13 terminal windows (gnome-terminal, xterm etc)
each window connects to a terminal server via ssh (`ssh InReach@10.1.6.254`)
and is provided the password via expect.

i can get this to work fine in a single window. the problem i am having though is getting the input passed over to each window.

for instance...

i can do

```
set timeout -1

spawn gnome-terminal -x ssh InReach@10.1.6.254
```

inside of a while loop and get my 13 windows. but i would like each one to be logged in automatically via expect.

Comment: I don't think you can control X applications with expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a slightly different approach. Instead of opening the terminal windows in the expect script, open them in a basic shell script, and have each terminal run an expect script to start a single SSH session.

So the expect script could be as simple as this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh InReach@10.1.6.254
# ... provide password ...
interact
```

And the shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for a in `seq 1 13`; do
    gnome-terminal -x ./expect_script
done
```

Answer (score 1):

When you spawn, you need to cache the $spawn_id value which is set by the attempt.
e.g.

```
if [catch "spawn ssh -l mtc $ub1_ip_address" ub1_pid] {
    Log $ERROR "Unable to spawn ssh to Xubuntu.\n$ub1_pid\n"
    return 0
}
set stored_id $spawn_id
```

To send a command to one terminal session in particular, do

`send -i $stored_id "command"`

Then, before you contact each, you must first do

```
 expect {
-i $stored_id
```

[ ... your regexes, globs, etc. ... ]

`}`

You can find some add'l info http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583

I would also suggest making use of gnome-terminal's ability to specify multiple tabs, including an indication of which is the currently-active one, and a command to be executed.  `gnome-terminal --help-all` is helpful (no pun intended).